# Why Bash Script loop is slow?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want use bash script to counting some number:

```
countnum=0

while [ $countnum -lt 200000 ];do
    countnum=$(($countnum + 1))
    # something else
done
```

Then I got:

```
$ time sh c.sh

real    0m3.981s
user    0m3.642s
sys 0m0.303s
```

**It lasts for about 4 seconds with any i/o?
Why ?**

The following is the time source and output of the cycle 2000w data written in java program. Took 53 milliseconds

```
public class AG {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int waitSplitNum = 20000000;
        int wegiht = 4;

        int cyclesize = waitSplitNum / wegiht;
        int remainder = waitSplitNum % wegiht;
        if (remainder > 0)
            cyclesize++;

        int tmpnum = 0;
        int countnum = 0;

        while (countnum < waitSplitNum) {
            tmpnum++;

            countnum++;

            if (tmpnum == cyclesize) {
                System.out.println((countnum - tmpnum + 1) + " " +     countnum);
                tmpnum = 0;
            }
        }
        if (tmpnum != 0)
            System.out.println((countnum - tmpnum + 1) + " " +     waitSplitNum);

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("spend time: " + (end - start) + " ms.");

    }
}
```

The output is:

```
1 5000000
5000001 10000000
10000001 15000000
15000001 20000000
spend time: 53 ms.
```

Comment: Because it's a script language. Feel free to improve the speed via source, then send the patch to upstream.

Comment: 4seconds is surprinsingly slow, are you sure it has nothing to do with `# something else` ? I get the loop done in under 2 seconds on ideone, and I'm sure it doesn't allocate much CPU to the scripts it lets you execute. Also, using `((countnum++))` instead of `countnum=$((countnum + 1))` significantly speeds things up. Ideone test here : https://ideone.com/botzv2

Comment: Are you sure the `sh` command is a bash on that system?

Comment: Yes, the confirmation is 4s. This cycle is only 20w, the same I used java to write 2000w also took 53 milliseconds.

Comment: But this is just a 20w loop, if 2000w I will not be able to imagine.

Comment: It's shell script, not a programming language. Shell is used for moving files and starting commands. Anything above a loop of 10 you should use something else.

Comment: @walkwolf: You might wanna give [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) a read.

Comment: With counting you already have some overhead, but it will get much worse when `# something else` is changed into an external program. Don't use the next small improvement either: `for (( i=0; i<200000; i++));do
    :
    # something else
done`

Comment: The 53 ms do not count the jvm startup.

Comment: [Updated ideone](https://ideone.com/8InGYj) based on @JamesBrown's suggestion : from 1.5s (original) to 1.2s(in-place incrementation) to 0.7s (in-place incrementation and `[[`)

Comment: @JamesBrown `[` is a builtin in dash and bash. If it actually did 200k forks, it would be even slower.